# Libgdx coordinates Gdx.input.getX() incorrect

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So I'm sitting here with a phone with a `800px` wide screen.. and `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` also returns 800 as it should..

But when I get coordinates from `Gdx.input.getX()` the highest number I get when touching the screen all the way to the left is around 780.. and around 20 in the right side..

So all my coordinates are wrong, so all my buttons and stuff are not working as they should etc.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Are you sure that you're tapping at the very very very end of the screen (which is nearly impossible)?
Usually, your finger is large and is far wider than 20px.

Comment: You should not need `Gdx.input.getX()` at all. Usually for buttons you will use `scene2d` which has buttons and correctly handles all input events for you.

Comment: ManuToMatic, I'm having it outputting the coordinate on all frames and I slowly move my finger over the edge of the phone and the last coordinate it outputs is 780 and not 800 as it should be.

Comment: Noone, my buttons of just textures, not "buttons".

Answer (score 0):

Try to unproject the coordinates.

```
Vector3 vec=new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(),0);
camera.unproject(vec);
// now use vec.x and vec.y instead of gdx.input.get...
```

Comment: Uhm what phone you got?

Answer (score 0):

Your coordinates are calculated from the other direction so you have to use

```
float ClickY = GameHeight - Gdx.input.getY();
```